# How to animate textures / how to read animation clips at an offset

Tags: python, animation, texturing, timeline

I've recently moved from unity to blender to try and make some music visualizations. A common effect I loved to create in unity was a pulsating effect where the beats of the music would pulsate through something. For an example see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=130cb8e-WF4
notice how the music pulsates through the particles.

Anyways I've found myself wanting to recreate this effect in blender and I've realized I'm a bit stuck. Currently I'd like to create the effect with a black and white texture so I can have the effect go through a model. The idea is I have to to somehow generate a texture based on the timelines position on an animation curve of baked sound. Then evaluate that animation curve back in time to create a delay across the texture as the animation plays. Thing is I don't even know where to start, and after researching python scripts for an hour I'm beginning to wonder if it's even possible. Can someone tell me if this is possible? and if so, point me in a direction where I can learn more about this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Blender! 
What exactly do you mean by "have the effect go through a model"?


Your approach seems a little overcomplicated to me. There are other, better tools for creating audio reactive particle systems in blender. One of which is an add-on called "animation nodes". there are a lot of tutorials online on how to use it for that exact same purpose.

Comment: I've actually never heard of animation nodes. I might look into that. Also when I say I want to the effect to go through the model what I mean is I want like a history of the amplitude of the audio mapped to different parts of the model creating a wave effect. Similar to the example I posted of what I made in unity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can bake your animation of the baked sound f-curve, so that it becomes editable.

Then you can use that f-curve value to modify any other value using drivers.

In my example the Y loc of the bone is driving the Y mapping of the texture, so the checker is moving up and down (on Y axis) following the music.

Check also the "stepped interpolation" f-curve modifier, to simplify the sound curve and have more punchy movements.

[image]

Comment: whoa, thanks for the in depth response. I'm aware of drivers, but I never realized I could bake action to edit the f-curves. I now can at least brute force the effect I want by animating different portions of the mesh with offset f-curves. Not ideal but it should work. Thanks!